Seeking a Linear Approximation for the Inverse of a Perturbed Pseudoinverse Matrix
I'm currently grappling with a challenge where I'm working with a matrix $L$, which is not of full rank, and its pseudoinverse $L^{+}$. My objective is to find a linear approximation for
$$ \left(L^{+} + \sigma^2 I\right)^{-1}, $$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix and $\sigma^2$ is a small perturbation term.
I attempted the matrix inverse approximation mentioned in this post on Stack Exchange, but the results were significantly unsatisfactory, because the rank of $L$ is not full.
Given this context, I am seeking alternative approaches or strategies that could yield a more effective linear approximation for
$$ \left(L^{+} + \sigma^2 I\right)^{-1}. $$
Any insights or suggestions on potential methods to explore would be greatly appreciated.

Convert$L^+$ to Jordan form?
